# How to set cascade delete in EF6 and in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have following relationship :

```
public class Company 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Round")]
        public ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Industry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IndustryName { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Industry")]
        public ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Division
    {
        [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Company")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 1), Key, ForeignKey("Industry")]
        public int IndustryId { get; set; }
        public string DivisionName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        [Key]
        public int WorkerId { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Division")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Division")]
        public int IndustryId { get; set; }
        public string WorkerName { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I want to set behaviour: when I delete Division , I don't want to delete workers, so what I need to do to make it work?

It will be great if solution will be for ef6 and ef core

Comment: It's all here: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Comment: @StevePy, thank You, but I try to do it from tutorials and documentation, but Im still has error and can't configure this deleting properly, that's why I post here.

Comment: For a start, CompanyId & IndustryId in Worker would need to be Null-able (`int?`) otherwise a Worker cannot exist without referencing a Division. That may set up the cascade behaviour automatically to not-delete, otherwise you would need to add configuration to the modelBuilder / config to disable cascade with an `OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.SetNull)`.